# Aggregate/Sampling Ultra high frequency time series data in Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, dataframe, time-series, sampling

I got a tough task to solve.
I am currently working with a very high frequency time series data. The data were measured in Millisecond/Microsecond. They are not equally spaced.

Noting that

**1 hour = 60 minutes = 3600 second.**

**1 second = 1,000 millisecond = 1,000,000 microsecond**

Thats why I say my data was ***ultra high frequency***.
The time series object in Matlab, as far as I know, only support second level data. I really need some convert my time series such as 10 millisecond data, or 100 millisecond data.

That means, for example, if I want my time series in 10 millisecond, the original data only have data points at 5th millisecond, 6th millisecond and 12 millisecond.

I will take the 6 millisecond as the most recent data point, regard it as the data at 10 millisecond.

Some times I need to summarize the data interval, but not very essential at the moment.

I reproduce some data as in the following:

```
TimeStamp=  
[66846720;67567616;67567617;67567618;67567619;67567620;67567621;67633152;...   
67633153;67633154;67633155;67633156;67633157;67633158;67633159;67633160;...   
67633161;67633162;482410496;495583232;495583233;807206912;1422721024;...
1596325888;1766457344];
Value = [2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;...
2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;...
2094.75 ;2094.75 ;2094.75;2094.75;2094.75;...
2094.75 ;2094.75 ;2094.75;2094.75;2094.5;...
2094.75 ;2094.75 ;2094.5  ;2094.5 ;2094.75;2094.5]
```

The **TimeStamp** is measured in millisecond and in **UTC time**

The way I am doing it is to generate a series of say m=10 millisecond, 
10,20,30,40.....

Then I find the nearest data points of each 10 millisecond using **a big for loop**, the efficiency is very low and usually took me a very long time to run...

**Please post any suggestions or good method, your kind help will be well appreciated**

**Other languages would be also nice if there are existing packages.**

Comment: Have you thought about storing data in a time-series database that supports millisecond precision and irregular time-series arrays?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov I want to do it in Matlab as one stop, thanks. Any database did you recommend ?

Comment: No particular recommendations for this use case, but there is a list of database on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database. You might want to check which ones provide a matlab client to simplify the integration.

Comment: Could you give a small example with input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

In R, you could consider using the `POSIXct` class for your timestamp.

In `?DateTimeClasses` we read that

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector.

Also note the parameter:

> **digits** Number of significant digits for the computations: should be high enough to represent the least important time unit exactly.

And note that the default value for **significant** digits is 15.  As there are 10 digits ahead of the decimal point in, for example, `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))`, that would leave 5 after the decimal point, or `1e-5` seconds precision, which is probably not enough, so perhaps use `digits=18` or `20` etc for some cushion.

To aggregate your observations to the nearest `1e-5` seconds (10 microseconds) you could then use `?round.POSIXt` as in:

```
round(x, units = "secs", digits=5)
```

where `x` is a vector, so you don't need a for loop.

Comment: Hi,@C8H10N4O2, what you mentioned in R is excellent, did you know similar functions in Matlab ?

Comment: Sorry @GeekCat but no, haven't used matlab for many years since school

Comment: @GeekCat You can use the posixtime function in Matlab to represent your time series using posix.